# Apple tvOS network not available notification

Tags: objective-c, tvos, reachability

I am using the `Reachability` class to check whether the network is available or not in my tvOS app.

When I try the notification `kReachabilityChangedNotification` its not calling the the method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNetworkChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

The method `handleNetworkChange` is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually post that notification?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Yes.. In iOS its working fine.

But in TvOS app its not working.

Comment: it will be taken care by Reachability class know